# MVC how to return a view after an IF statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My page has a search box which for has a few radio buttons. Depending on which radio button is selected will depend on which view is shown.

However, I don't know how to return the View.

My code is

```
 public ActionResult Index(string jobType)
    {
        if (jobType.ToLower() == "this")
            CandidateResults();
        else
            JobResults();
    }

    private ActionResult CandidateResults()
    {
        var model = //logic
        return View(model);
    }
    private ActionResult JobResults()
    {
        var model = //logic
        return View(model);
    }
```

But this displays nothing on screen (a white page). This makes sense but I **don't** want to return Index, I want to return a new page (called either JobResults or Candidates) and create a View for both of these new pages but when I right click in my methods (JobResults() or Candidates()) I don't get the option to Add View.

At this stage I'm lost, can any one please give advice.

Comment: do you want the page to change on the selection of the radio button or upon clicking a button or action link?

Comment: @Robert - Either. The issue the radiobuttons are in the form which points to Index, but I don't want to return that page, I want either my CandidateResult or JobResult view not only be returned but the URL to be reflected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either return the view from Index or redirect to CandidateResults or JobResults actions.

```
public ActionResult Index(string jobType)
{
    if (jobType.ToLower() == "this")
        return CandidateResults();
    else
        return JobResults();
}

private ActionResult CandidateResults()
{
    var model = //logic
    return View(model);
}
private ActionResult JobResults()
{
    var model = //logic
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public ActionResult Index(string jobType)
{
    return (jobType.ToLower() == "this") ?
        RedirectToAction("CandidateResults") :
        RedirectToAction("JobResults");
}

private ActionResult CandidateResults()
{
    var model = //logic
    return View(model);
}
private ActionResult JobResults()
{
    var model = //logic
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: This probably won't work since the actions you are redirecting to are private.  Also you only need to switch on the name name in the string, the `RedirectToAction` part is duplicated.

Comment: Thank you @NickLarsen but, using RedirectToAction coupled with making it public has resolved the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your private methods you have to specify the actual view you want to display.

```
public ActionResult Index(string jobType)
{
    if (jobType.ToLower() == "this")
        CandidateResults();
    else
        JobResults();
}

private ActionResult CandidateResults()
{
    var model = //logic
    return View("CandidateResults", model);
}
private ActionResult JobResults()
{
    var model = //logic
    return View("JobResults", model);
}
```

This happens because of the way the view engine works.  The action name for the current request is always `Index` when the index function is called.  Even if you call another method, the view engine will use the name of the current action and not the name of the currently executing function.

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to redirect the user to proper controller method and that method will return its `View` as below:

```
public ActionResult Index(string jobType)
    {
        if (jobType.ToLower() == "this")
            return RedirectToAction("CandidateResults","ControllerName");
        else
            return RedirectToAction("JobResults","ControllerName");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Index(string jobType)
{
    if (jobType.ToLower() == "this")
        return RedirectToAction("CandidateResults");

    return RedirectToAction("JobResults");
}

private ActionResult CandidateResults()
{
    var model = //logic
    return View(model);
}
private ActionResult JobResults()
{
    var model = //logic
    return View(model);
}
```